# Rails apply if statement to loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have polls that can be published or unpublished. Admin can see all, other only published ones.

I tried:

```
<% if current_user.admin_role? %>
  <% @polls.each do |poll| %>
<% else %>
  <% @published_polls.each do |poll| %>
  <% end %>
  <!-- content -->
<% end %>
```

But comes out a syntax error: `unexpected keyword_else`.

Syntax looks good to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need `end` after `<% @polls.each do |poll| %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd do the if statement in a controller, something like:

```
@display_polls = current_user.admin_role? ? @polls : @published_polls
```

And then in your view:

```
<% @display_polls.each do |poll| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

IMO, you don't want logic in your views.

Comment: A decorator would be better, I think.

Comment: Agreed! But, I was thinking that might be a more advanced topic. This seemed like a short, but reasonable, line between Q and A.

Comment: And, actually, I don't even do `.each` loops in my views anymore. These days, mine tend to look more like `= @presenter.polls` and I just push everything into a presenter method.

Comment: Moving the logic from view was something I wanted to achieve eventually. Even better if done already :) I'll look into dropping .each loops too. Thanks for all tips!